# Socket.IO namespaces won't work

Tags: node.js, socket.io, namespaces

I am trying to make a socket.io node chat room application
And my dependices are 
socket.io@1.4.5 
 node@v5.7.0
At client side I added

```
window.onload = function(){

        + var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:4000/chat');
        var messagesElement = document.getElementById('messages');
        var lastMessageElement = null;
```

And the server side I added

```
- io.sockets.on('connection',function(socket){
   + io.of('/chat').on('connection',function(socket){
```

Before those changes the application works fine
When I am trying to use socket.io namespaces to 

separate different applications on the server
and on the client.
 
It doesn't work and I don't find any error or bug on the console.

[My application's repository link](https://github.com/magelon/socketio)

Answer (score 1):

I just found there is a same variable below the socket variable in the client side

```
        <script>
window.onload = function(){
      + var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:4000/chat');
      var socket = io.connect('/chat');
            var messagesElement = document.getElementById('messages');
            var lastMessageElement = null;

@@ -36,7 +36,7 @@ window.onload = function(){
                lastMessageElement=newMessageElement;
            }
    here--> -var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:4000');
   +//var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:4000');
        socket.on('serverMessage',function(content){
            addMessage(content);
        });
```

And I comment it, it works now.